# Как объяснить логическую разницу (различия в логике проектирования) между java-пакетом и классом

Tags: java

У меня возник вопрос
Как объяснить логическую разницу (различия в логике проектирования) между java-пакетом и классом.
Спасибо за внимание

Comment: пакет это грубо говоря папка, в которой лежат файлы. Класс это файл который джава машина компилирует в байт код.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ

Comment: Пакеты как правило должны быть многоуровневые, представляющие из себя доменное имя организации в обратном порядке, очень важная вещь, если речь идет о хорошей программе